# Subscript out of range Midcoded error

Tags: vba, excel

Usually with a subscript out of range error, something is misspelled. This time I can guarantee that it is not misspelled. I am declaring workbook and sheets names as variables to be used later for simple copy paste stuff. But when I define one of my sheets as `Set main=wb.Sheets("Primary")` I get the error, subscript out of range. I did't believe it, so I copied what I wrote and pasted that as the Sheet name. Same error. Therefore, their must be an issue with how I set up my Workbook/Worksheets. Any help much appreciated.

```
Sub copyPaste()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim main As Sheets
Dim hypo As Sheets

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Set main = wb.Sheets("Primary")
Set hypo = wb.Sheets("Hypo")

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wb.main.Range("D22:D46").Value = wb.main.Range("D22:D46").Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have `"Primary"` and not e.g. `"Primary "`?

Comment: I am positive that their are no spaces.

Comment: Are you sure that they are in the same workbook?

Comment: Rebooted it. Works fine. ugh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `Worksheet` (singular) not `Sheets` (plural) (`Sheets` is a collection of worksheets)

```
Dim main As WorkSheet
Dim hypo As WorkSheet
```

and here you dont use the workbook object because it's already defined as part of the worksheet reference. Change it to this

```
main.Range("D22:D46").Value = main.Range("D22:D46").Value
```

Comment: Worked just fine for me when I tested it.

Comment: Doesn't like any name I give it.

Comment: Rebooted it. Works fine. ugh